# Can we customize WPF MenuItem style on IsPressed

Tags: wpf, menuitem, mahapps.metro

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<mah:MetroWindow x:Class="Wpf_MahAppsTEST.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_MahAppsTEST"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="850" Width="800">
    <mah:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.MenuItem.SelectionFill" Color="{StaticResource MahApps.Colors.Accent3}" />
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.MenuItem}" TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="MenuStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.IdealForeground}"/>
        </Style>
    </mah:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuStyle}"/>
                </MenuItem.Resources>
                <MenuItem Header="_New" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Open" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</mah:MetroWindow>
```

**Display of above window:**

As shown below, when we press ([Ref: MenuITem.IsPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.menuitem.ispressed?view=net-5.0)) the `File` item of the menu, the background of the `File` item is showing as default (gray). **Question**  How can we make the background of the `File` item look the same as the background of its child items when you mouse over a child item (such as the background of `Open` item as depicted below)?

[image]

For example, (without MahApps), the default look as follows - where background of both the File item and the `Open` item match. I am looking for a similar scenario in the above example for MahApp:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another brush resource:

```
<mah:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.TopMenuItem.PressedFill"
                     Color="{StaticResource MahApps.Colors.Accent3}" />
    
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.MenuItem.SelectionFill" Color="{StaticResource MahApps.Colors.Accent3}" />
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.MenuItem}" TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="MenuStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.IdealForeground}"/>
    </Style>
</mah:MetroWindow.Resources>
```